# 'Device Connected' sound plays on Windows 10 over and over

Tags: windows-10, usb, event-log

I keep getting the 'Device Connected' Sound on my Windows 10 PC. It plays repeatedly, anywhere from about a minute between each one to playing several in quick succession.

I've installed USBLogView but it doesn't show anything.

I've tried disabling the USB Selective Suspend setting as I saw recommended to other people having this issue.

My device manager tab shows that no devices are having issues.

It appears that every time the sound plays the 'Safely Eject Hardware' shows up in my System Tray for a little less than a tenth of a second. [You can see a gif of that happening here.](https://gfycat.com/embarrassedlasthornedviper)

I installed EventGhost and I'm seeing `System.DeviceAttached [u'\\\\?\\USB#VID_046D&PID_081B#9356D700#{a5dcbf10-6530-11d2-901f-00c04fb951ed}']` followed by a `System.DeviceRemoved` one with the same text afterwards come up super often. I think this is the issue, but I have no idea how to interpret the event.

How can I find out what's causing this and then disable it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The string
[VID_046D&PID_081B](https://www.driveridentifier.com/scan/logitech-usb-camera-hd-webcam-c310/driver-detail/5CA4AED9A76243C4B47F8F1F3B668903/714365/21ce491e1b72fea407e4c2bc10c19171/268255513/USB%5cVID_046D&PID_081B)
identifies the Logitech USB Camera HD Webcam C310 as the problem device.
Something is wrong with the webcam or with the port it is connected to.

I suggest connecting it to another port, or even another computer, to identify
the cause of the problem.

Comment: It is also possible your power supply is not providing enough power for your entire system and as a result your USB has just too little power for a strong connection. A power fluctuation on the mains can then cause for any device to be briefly disconnected. It will usually be the same device though.